# How can an attribute be added to invoice line items?

Tags: attributes, magento-1, invoice, eav

Our business has recently run into the need to have the actual price of an item on the invoice, as well as what it's price paid is if its on sale.  The price paid is included on the invoice object, but finding actual price of the item is impossible since the actual price may have changed since it was purchased.

I understand the mechanics of the EAV system, and i am going to do a lot of research on this problem and probably have to code a custom solution, but i thought i'd throw the question out here in case i'm missing something obvious.  I am planning on approaching this from the viewpoint of "I need a custom module with table modifications"

I need this feature for audit reasons, so no looking in the admin log for price change history.

EDIT:
Found http://www.atwix.com/magento/custom-product-attribute-quote-order-item/

Also, github project https://bitbucket.org/vovsky/adding-custom-product-attribute-to-quote-and-order-items-in/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up writing a small Magento Module based on information I found at the following links:

http://www.atwix.com/magento/custom-product-attribute-quote-order-item/
https://bitbucket.org/vovsky/adding-custom-product-attribute-to-quote-and-order-items-in/
http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-6-magento-setup-resources

I think the scope of the question asked was much too broad to post a specific answer, but if I were to give one, it would be...

The right way of accomplishing this is to create a custom module that extends the 
'quote',
'quote_address',
'quote_item',
'quote_address_item',
'order',
'order_item'

entities and write to them using an Observer on the  event.